# Subscribers become Authors after Upgrade? / Mass Update of Users?

Tags: wp-admin, users, upgrade, updates

I have a site with ~30K users, and the vast majority have role `'subscriber'` on the main blog. After upgrading from WPMU 2.9.2 to WordPress 3.0.1 I noticed that all 30,0000 users are appearing in the main blog's *"Author"* dropdown in `post-new.php`. *(Well, that is if it manages to load without crashing the browser...)*.

To clarify: the users all still have subscriber-level access, but are included in *"Author"* dropdown.

Before I go diving down in to the guts of `/wp-admin/`, has anyone else seen this? Does anyone know if this behavior is an intentional change in WordPress?

Thanks,
Bethany

Comment: That's a *very* serious bug. Any chances you've reported it in core.trac.wordpress.org?

Answer (score 2):

Hi **@Bee**:

I have no idea why this happened.  But if I understand your problem correctly you need to set these user records back to being `'subscriber'` instead of `'author'`, right?

Normally I would not recommend direct SQL update like this but given the nature of the problem and it being a one-time thing I think it will be okay.

But **first** [BACK UP YOUR DATABASE](http://codex.wordpress.org/Backing_Up_Your_Database) before you try any of this.

Here's the SQL to run based on what I know of the internals of WordPress and also based on [this support question](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/mass-change-user-role) *(this assumes that the prefix for your main tables is `'wp'` and also assumes you are okay to set all users assigned to with `'author'` back to subscriber and manually make any corrections using the WordPress admin console.)* So if you know how to run this SQL from a SQL query tool, go for it:

```
UPDATE 
  wp_usermeta 
SET 
  meta_value='a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";s:1:"1";}'
WHERE 1=1
  AND meta_key='wp_capabilities' 
  AND meta_value LIKE '%author%'
```

If you are not comfortable with running SQL from a query tools then you can drop this into the *root* of your website (call it `/update-users.php` or similar) and then run it by calling the URL `http://example.com/update-users.php` from your browser *(replacing `http://example.com` with your actual site domain, of course):*

```
<?php
include "wp-load.php";
global $wpdb;
$sql =<<<SQL
UDPATE
  wp_usermeta
SET
  meta_value='a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";s:1:"1";}'
WHERE 1=1
  AND meta_key='wp_capabilities'
  AND meta_value LIKE '%author%'
SQL;
$wpdb->query($sql);
echo 'Done!';
```

P.S. Please report back to us on your success, or if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Mike! If only it were so simple :) but the users are all still set at 'subscriber' level permissions on the blog, and yet are getting added to the Author menu. I'll update the question to clarify.

Comment: @Bee - Hmm. Hard to diagnose that problem without having it duplicated on my end. Any chance you have a plugin that is introducing that error?